# JavaScript Collapse open by default

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that is working, however, I want to reverse it. I want them to be open by default, and when clicked, they collapse.

Any help would be appreciated.

This was found on w3 schools.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_animate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.collapsible:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 13px;
    color: blue;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;

  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>

<p>A Collapsible:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = 0  + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much. the animation was nice, but not needed. thanks again